# Trust anchor for certification path not found with okhttp

Tags: android, ssl, https, retrofit, okhttp

So I've been trying all night to make it work, but nothing seems to do the trick ... I keep getting Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Here is how I'm build the okhttpClient (I followed https://medium.com/@sreekumar_av/certificate-public-key-pinning-in-android-using-retrofit-2-0-74140800025b)

```
fun provideOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
    val httpClientBuilder = OkHttpClient()
            .newBuilder()

    val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    logging.level = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    else
        HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE


    val certificatePinner = CertificatePinner.Builder()
            .add(HOST, SHA)
            .build()

    val connectionSpec = ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
    connectionSpec.tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2).build()

    val tlsSocketFactory = TLSSocketFactory()
    return httpClientBuilder
            .certificatePinner(certificatePinner)
            .addNetworkInterceptor(logging)
            .sslSocketFactory(tlsSocketFactory, tlsSocketFactory.systemDefaultTrustManager())
            .connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(connectionSpec.build()))
            .build()
}
```

I got the sha like this: openssl s_client -connect host:port | openssl x509 -pubkey -noout | openssl rsa -pubin -outform der | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64

and here is the TLSFacotry: https://gist.github.com/pollux-/fbcc74984e110bb49497faa2d0ed5ee1#file-tlssocketfactory-java

I really don't get why it doesn't work at that point..

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: IIRC, the full LogCat output will show what OkHttp encountered, so you can compare it with what you have in your `certificatePinner`. And I do not know why you have that `sslSocketFactory()` call.

Comment: I don't have really much more info on the logcat but here is the full log:
https://gist.github.com/NeoDigi/60abbcdd1f650897f600afda9268837b

Comment: It wouldn't be in the stack trace, but in lines before or after it.

Comment: There is nothing more, maybe there there is an interceptor or something that I can add to have more info, but as of now, there is really nothing more

Comment: Remove everything but `certificatePinner()` from the `httpClientBuilder` and try it again. You're looking for the "Certificate pinning failure!" lines as described in [the JavaDocs for `CertificatePinner`](http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/CertificatePinner.html).

Comment: When I only add the certificatePinner and I try to make it fail on purpose as in the link that you provided, i'm still just having: Trust anchor for certification path not found. with no other log

Comment: Are you on a fairly current version of OkHttp? If so, then I don't know what to suggest at this point. AFAIK, you really don't want that `sslSocketFactory()` call, as that should clobber your `certificatePinner()` and `connectionSpecs()`.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC certificate pinning is only evaluated *after* the certificate chain is accepted.

It would help to have the full stacktrace, and the host you are trying to connect to, since it is possible it is using a self signed certificate that your client won't accept.

Try to get it working without certificate pinning first, then add it in.  As @CommonsWare mentions when certificate pinning fails it tells you what to do.